# Origine de l'expression "trouze-mille"

Tags: expressions, étymologie, nombres, origine-ou-raison

L'expression "trouze-mille" est une expression que j'entends régulièrement pour parler d'un grand chiffre, sans plus de précision.

Pourtant, je ne trouve que de très rare définitions. Aucun des dictionnaires que j'ai consulté ne contenait "trouze". Les seules références que j'ai trouvé en ligne sont sur le [Définistaire](http://www.definistaire.org/dictionnaire-des-mots-qui-n-existent-pas/trouze-1630) et une page anglaise de [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language#Numbers_2) :

> Quarante-douze (forty-twelve) and trouze mille (probably short for trente-douze mille, thirty-twelve thousand) are used for random numbers and particularly high random numbers respectively.

Évidemment ces deux sources ne sont pas les plus fiables.

[Google Tendances](https://www.google.fr/trends/explore#q=trouze&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-2) atteste aussi de l'utilisation du mot "trouze" (en très petit nombres, mais elle existe).

Je me demande donc : quelle est l'origine de l'expression "trouze-mille", ou du mot "trouze" ?

Comment: Jamais entendu. C'est pas plutôt "treize" mille avec un accent ? :)

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "trouze". En tout état de cause, il s'agit d'une forme pour le moins familière, probablement le mélange cocasse de "douze" et "treize", comme le dit Anne Aunyme (pourquoi d'ailleurs le dit-elle en Anglais, puisque cette page est en français?). Dans ce cas, il s'agit d'une de ces innombrables fantaisies que chacun peut se permettre dans certaines circonstances, sans qu'il y ait lieu d'en faire un sujet de discussion.

Comment: l'habitude de répondre à des questions en anglais, c'est corrigé :). Je confirme en tous cas qu'il s'agit bien d'une expression idiomatique couramment employée en français et pas simplement d'une fantaisie d'une personne isolée.

Comment: Je suis vraiment très intrigué par cette existence supposée : En tout état de cause, ce mot ne figure dans aucun dictionnaire, semble-t-il: S'agit-il d'une invention toute récente, comme le "morgane" de Renaud Séchan, ou le "pile-poil" des Guignols de l'Info, ou comme les innombrables mots de "verlan" qui se sont jetés sur la langue comme une vérole?

Comment: @BBBreiz Trouze a été ajouté au [dictionnaire  des mots qui n'existent pas](http://www.definistaire.org/dictionnaire-des-mots-qui-n-existent-pas) en 2003, donc certainement pas beaucoup plus vieux.

Comment: Merci, Laure, pour ce dictionnaire rafraîchissant, où la présence de "trouze" jette un doute sur la validité de l'agrément accordé par Anne Aunyme à ce mot mystérieux...

Comment: @BBBreiz Mais il y a des mots qui [existent bel et bien](http://www.definistaire.org/dictionnaire-des-mots-qui-n-existent-pas/conciliabule-5525) dans ce dictionnaire ! Leur définition est complètement fantaisiste et "trouze" n'en fait sûrement pas partie, mais ils existent. Pour "trouze", peut-être que son utilisation est restreinte à une aire géographique limitée, ce qui pourrait expliquer que seuls moi et Anne Aunyme le connaisse.

Comment: pile-poil existe aussi: http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pile-poil/60908. Il en est d'ailleurs de même pour beaucoup de mots de verlan.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Pile-poil n'est pas du verlan (trouze-mille non plus d'ailleurs), et figure depuis longtemps dans la plupart des dictionnaires les dictionnaires (premier emploi attesté dans le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française : 1995).

Comment: Laure: c'était une réponse à BBBreiz: "S'agit-il d'une invention toute récente, comme le "morgane" de Renaud Séchan, ou le "pile-poil" des Guignols de l'Info ?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probablement un mélange entre "treize" (13) et "douze" (12), qui donne "trouze". L'idée étant de faire un mot qui sonne comme un nombre, sans en être un. On a un exemple similaire en anglais pour "gazillion" par exemple.

Notez au passage qu'on n'utilise jamais "trouze" tout seul, c'est toujours "trouze-mille" (parfois orthographié "trouzemille", à tort depuis la dernière réforme).

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar expression but it's ''Douze mille'' so..like other people I'm not sure if trouze mille is something or the accent.